# "WHERE IN" equivalent in MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mysql, mongodb, aggregation-framework, match

I'm trying to filter elements in my MongoDB doc based on if they exist in an array I call `DispatchIDFilter`.

Doing this in MySQL is pretty simple...

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT KernelName from dbName.table1 where `Index` in ($DispatchIDFilter)
```

but I've ran into some errors when trying to do the same in Mongo using `match`...

```js
db.table1.aggregate([
    {"$match": {
      "$expr": {"$in": $DispatchIDFilter}
    }}
    {"$group": {
      "_id": "$KernelName"
    }}
]);
```

I'm not sure that my current implementation is right, but I was hoping that someone could show me the proper way to accomplish this using `match`.

Comment: Is the field you're trying to match against named `Index`?

Comment: Have your checked out the [official $in documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/)?

Comment: Is the `DispatchIDFilter` an external variable _or_ a field within the same table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are providing the an *array* variable `DispatchIDFilter` you can write the query as follows:

```
db.table1.distinct("KernelName", { "Index": { $in: DispatchIDFilter } } )
```

OR

```
db.table1.aggregate([
    { $match: { "Index": { $in: DispatchIDFilter } } },
    { $group: { _id: "$KernelName" } }
])
```

The first query is a MongoDB Query Language (MQL) and returns (outputs) the distinct `KernalName` values as an array. See [db.collection.distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/).

The second is an Aggregation query. The output returns a *cursor* with documents having distinct `KernalName` values. Note that a document has key-values.